# Code in electron renderer process not working after packaging

Tags: socket.io, electron, electron-packager

code from index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- All of the Node.js APIs are available in this renderer process. -->
    We are using Node.js <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chromium <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
  <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>

<form><input></form><div></div>
</html>
```

code in renderer.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
var os = require('os');
var fs = require('fs');

io.listen(6000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('my socketId', function (data) {
    socket.emit('client connect', {
      nickname: os.hostname()
    });
  });
});
```

Problem: It works fine using `electron .` running in browser. But client got no respond after packaging by electron-packager.

Thank you very much for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem. I was copying the app to build first. But node_modules (and those packages) didn't exist in that directory. Either copy it or run npm install in build before running Electron Packager will make it work.